# Is there a mount for GoPros that clamp the gopro itself instead of using thumbscrews?

Tags: action-cam, gopro

I'm having trouble finding a mount for GoPro/any general action camera that uses clamping to hold the device down instead of an external case or thumb screws.

Basically I'm looking for something like this:

[image]

Only, I'm looking for one that can clamp down on something smaller than a smartphone because the one for smartphone doesn't close up enough.

If there aren't any out there, what are some alternatives that people have used so they can quickly remove the action cam from whatever it's mounted on aside from the [quick release](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jh7zG.png) things?